# what does sudo su - s option means

Tags: sudo, su

I have used 'sudo su -' many times and I know what it does actually.
I wanted to know what does this mean --> 'sudo su -s /bin/bash userid'

I googled and iam not able to identify what i actually need.

Please help with your valid comments.

Thanks
Muthu.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

Check out `man su`

But in a nutshell, `su -s` denotes what "shell" you want to use. In your example, you are telling it to use `/bin/bash` for shell. The userid is the username of the account you want to "switch user" to.

And then on top of that, you put it into `sudo`.

If you want to clarify exactly what you want to do, perhaps we can provide better answer.

Comment: Thank you Darius for your response.
Normally when you do a 'sudo su -' , it takes the default shell value from /etc/passwd.
Here in this case, it is pointing to /bin/bash instead of default one.
What is the benefit of using '/bin/bash' ? Does it provide any restricted access for the user or it is given for some purpose? 
I just wanted to know this stuff as Iam seeing it as a requirement here in one of our situation.

Comment: It probably is better to just use sudo, without su. It has functionality you require.